# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug'. >

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am trying to integrate AWS Mobile Hub for uploading media files

```
compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.7@aar') { transitive = true; }
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.14'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.14'
```

I am not able to build APK

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug'.

> Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.

Comment: Can you give more information about the stacktrace and the build output?

Comment: To enable this build task I added the following configuration information to the build.gradle file and did a clean and build. I did not face any issues. Can you give more information on how you triggered this gradle task?   buildTypes {
        debug {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
        }
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }